# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{F}_{n}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{F}_n =\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{O}(n)\oplus\mathcal{O})$ with $n\geq1$. I was trying to calculate $Aut(\mathbb{F}_{n}) = G$. It is not hard to see that an automorphism maps fibres (of the $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle) to fibres so there is a morphism $G \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{P}^1) = PGl_2$. My question is about the kernel, I have read that this semi-direct product of $\mathbb{C}^*$ with $H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(n))$. This doesn't look so random since $\mathbb{F}_n = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(n)\oplus \mathcal{O})$, I can see how $ \mathbb{C}^*$ acts by multiplication on the trivial factor, but how does the semi-direct product act?

Comment: I am not sure how standard or well-known the terminology $\mathbb{F}_n$ is but maybe just for the convenience of the users, the question should begin with definitions of (new) notations.

Comment: Ok, I did this.

Comment: When you write $Aut(\mathbb{F}_n)$ I understand that you mean the automorphism of the entire scheme?

Comment: Just the group of biregular morphisms of this variety.

Comment: The kernel looks like the set of all automorphism of the projective bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$. This is same as(? I am not totally sure of this statement) automorphism induced by automorphism of the vector bundle $\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(n)$. This can be easily calculated to be what is required.

Comment: Maybe the map to $PGL_2$ should be interpreted as following : Let $s$ be a section of $\pi : \mathbb{F}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. Then we have $Aut(\mathbb{F}_n) \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{P}^1)$ given by $\phi \mapsto \pi \circ \phi \circ s$. Again I am not sure. But this seems natural, but I am finding it difficult to see as to why kernel is the set of maps which are automorphism of the projective bundle.